# Conditional probability question for RL value function and the action-value function

Tags: probability, reinforcement-learning, conditional-expectation

Per this [link on Deep RL](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro.html#value-functions) (context not required, this is just a conditional probability question) we have:

1. The On-Policy Value Function, $V^{\pi}(s)$, which gives the expected return if you start in state $s$ and always act according to policy $\pi$:

$$ V^{\pi}(s) = \underset{\tau \sim \pi}{\mathbb E}[R(\tau) \mid s_0 = s]$$

2. The On-Policy Action-Value Function, $Q^{\pi}(s,a)$, which gives the expected return if you start in state $s$, take an arbitrary action $a$ (which may not have come from the policy), and then forever after act according to policy $\pi$:

$$ Q^{\pi}(s, a) = \underset{\tau \sim \pi}{\mathbb E}[R(\tau) \mid s_0 = s, a_0 = a]$$

It's then noted that:

$$V^{\pi}(s) = \underset{a \sim \pi}{\mathbb E}[Q^{\pi}(s,a) ]$$

which makes sense. My question is should this not technically be:

$$V^{\pi}(s)  = \underset{a \sim \pi}{\mathbb E}[Q^{\pi}(s,a) \mid s ] $$

I *know* this seems pedantic - I just want to check I understand/haven't missed anything.

Comment: The subscript below $\mathbb{E}$ indicates the distribution w.r.t. which the integral is taken; everything else is held fixed.

Comment: Sorry to be awkward - so that's a "yes" then?

Comment: not really...the conditioning doesn't add anything new.